# Can't get "IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility" installed on Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis

I'm trying to get Visual Studio setup to be able to use my local IIS server for hosting projects-- it tells me I need to install "IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility". So I have tried to do so via Add/Remove Windows Components. The installation process gets to the end and then states that an error has occurred and not all components could be installed (helpful, right?) Then asks me to reboot-- upon reboot, the feature is not installed.

Has anyone experienced this problem under Windows 7 before? I am running the 64-bit Ultimate edition if it matters.

I've also tried completely uninstalling IIS (that worked) then reinstalling with "IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility" checked -- same failure at the end of the install.

There is a \Windows\IIS7.log file I can use for debugging but it's fairly large and random.. I don't see anything that screams "fatal error".

Answer (score 4):

I've also had the same problem using Visual Studio 2010 on Vista, but I've got this answer back from Geoffrey, provided his address below...wonder if that would also work for Windows 7.

Im in the process of installing Windows 7 on my laptop and wonder if you are able to fix your error with the answer I received then I will follow the same procedure once I've installed Windows 7 to fix the error

heres the address... follow is thru...it fixed my error. hope it'll help fix your error...

http://blog.geoffreyemery.com/post/iis-6-metabase-and-iis-6-configuration-compatibility-error.aspx

Chers
Frances

Comment: the above link is dead :(

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  Same symptom trying to install it fails and reboot rolls back install.

with Microsoft support the following resolved the issue.

1. Enabled Administrator Account on Windows 7 machine using following command net user administrator /active:yes
2. Logged in as administrator account on Windows 7 machine
3. Installed IS 6 Management Compatibility,IIS 6 Management Console,IIS 6 Management Scripts and Tools and IIS 6 Management Service components.

Even though my account was in the administrators group..that was not enough I had to be logged in as the administrator to resolve this issue.